# write to excel cell using the namedrange instead of cell notation like (A1,A2) using PHP

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

I am writing to excel using PHP_Excel. I am using

```
$object->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue("A1", utf8_encode("$var"));
```

Is there any way that instead of using the Cell (A1) itself i can use the namedrange. I already name the cell in excel file ?

Comment: Any way other then setting a cell value by column and row method or setting a cell value by coordinate

Answer (score 1):

This is what I suggest you:

**1)** Create a multidimensional array by repeating your variable...

```
$var = utf8_encode("MyString");
$arr = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < 10; ++$i)
{
  for ($j = 0; $j < 10; ++$j)
    $arr[$i][] = $var;
}
```

**2)** Populate the Excel spreadsheet using `fromArray` (where `A1` is the top left coordinate of your final data)...

```
$object->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($arr, NULL, 'A1');
```

One way or another, even if you don't want to use `setCellValueByColumnAndRow` (which would save you one step with a little drawback on the performance), you will have to put your code into an iteration.

Comment: I don't think it is possible so i am first getting the cell from excel file using some value and then use those cells for writing. But for that I need a reference file in excel.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand this... may you clarify your statement please?

Comment: To accommodate the probelm that i cannot use given name of cell instead of cell numbering like (A1, B1, etc), I use a reference sheet and then use that reference sheet to write my excel file dynamically.

Comment: Ok... but if you want to fit many cells at once without looping through every cell name of without using `setCellValueByColumnAndRow`, this is the only way left. You create an array, and then you fill the target cells with it, starting from the top left corned represented by `A1`.

Comment: yes but i need to know the cell address where mysql data will go and with looping. It will get that address from a mysql table where it is saved from the reference excel file. If we want to change any cell in future we do not need to change in the database just change it in reference excel file run the php and the database automatically updated. Then we can use the table to fill the excel file.